# Display image using Angular 4 src

Tags: angular, data-binding, mean

Using AngularJS it was possible displaying images like this:

```
ng-src="public/img/{{item.image}}"
```

Where `{{item.image}}` is stored in MongoDB.

My question therefore is pretty straightforward... How would I achieve the same thing in Angular 4?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
<img src = "public/img/{{item.image}}">
```

Or alternatively as Pankaj pointed out:

```
<img [src] = "'public/img/' + item.image">
```

There is a chapter in the Angular docs that map AngularJS features to Angular features that may be helpful:

https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-src

Comment: I know you must have mistakenly missed it. You might want to do like `[src]="'public/img/'+item.image"`?

Comment: Yea, I just cut and pasted his right hand side. So my original answer is not actually correct. I'll update it. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

With either of these :

```
<img src="public/img/{{item.image}}" />
<img [src]="'public/img/'+item.image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works as well:

```
<img [src] = `public/img/${item.image}`>
```

**Use backticks instead of single or double quotes and ${variable_name}.**